# Disabling weak ciphers

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, ssl, windows-registry

Does anyone have any experience disabling weak ciphers on Windows Registry? Server doesn't have IIS installed. Below is the results of my security scan but not 100% what registry entries should be added, i've disabled whole protocols via the registry before but never individual ciphers.

Guessing the registry keys would be created here.

```
HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\
```

Here is the list of weak SSL ciphers supported by the remote server :

```
  Low Strength Ciphers (< 56-bit key)

    TLSv1
      EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA      Kx=DH(512)     Au=RSA      Enc=DES-CBC(40)          Mac=SHA1   export     
      EXP-DES-CBC-SHA              Kx=RSA(512)    Au=RSA      Enc=DES-CBC(40)          Mac=SHA1   export     
      EXP-RC4-MD5                  Kx=RSA(512)    Au=RSA      Enc=RC4(40)              Mac=MD5    export     

The fields above are :

  {OpenSSL ciphername}
  Kx={key exchange}
  Au={authentication}
  Enc={symmetric encryption method}
  Mac={message authentication code}
  {export flag}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Guessing the registry keys would be created here.

You don't have to guess. [Le Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel] 
"EventLogging"=dword:00000001 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Ciphers] 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\CipherSuites] 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Hashes] 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\KeyExchangeAlgorithms] 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols] 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\SSL 2.0] 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client] 
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
```

So your hunch was close, but note the Ciphers subkey when you want to enable/disable ciphers, and the Protocols subkey when you want to disable/enable entire protocols.

So for instance, if you want to disable RC4, create several new keys, one for each different key size that could be used in RC4:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 56/128

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64/128

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 128/128
```

In each one of those keys, you need to create the new value:

```
Enabled    REG_DWORD    0
```

If you wanted to disable, for example, the entire SSL v2 protocol, create the keys:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server
```

Inside each key, make two new values:

```
Enabled              DWORD    0
DisabledByDefault    DWORD    1
```

Note that these policies only affect applications which link to/call into Schannel.dll... so IIS, Internet Explorer, Remote Desktop, etc.  These settings will not affect applications that use other SSL libraries such as OpenSSL.